# Trying to read lines from an ASCII file using C++ , Ubuntu vs Mac...?

Tags: c++

I have an ASCII file (students.txt) that looks as follows (Ignore empty lines, they're an artifact of my unfamiliarity with this formatting tool):

```
stella 10 4.4 ...
peter 1.1 5 ...
```

That is, each line starts with a name, followed by one or more numbers.

The code snippet below is meant to read this file line by line, reading the name into a string and the numbers into a double, printing each of these in turn. When I run this on Ubuntu, it works fine and I get

```
stella 10 4.4
peter 1.1 5
```

However, when I run it on a Mac, I get the following:

```
stella 10 4.4
ter 1.1 5
```

When I change 'peter' to 'speter', however, it works fine...:

```
stella 10 4.4
speter 1.1 5
```

Any thoughts...?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main() {

  ifstream infile("students.txt");
  string name;
  double x;

  while ( !infile.eof() ) {
    infile >> name;
    cout << name << ' ';
    while ( infile >> x ){
      cout << x << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
    if (! infile.eof() )
      infile.clear();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Answer (score 0):

When the input starts out divided into lines, it's usually easiest to read it by lines, then split those into the component pieces:

```
std::string line;

std::string name;
std::vector<double> values;

while (std::getline(infile, line)) {
    std::istringstream buffer(line);
    double temp;

    buffer >> name;
    while (buffer >> temp)
        values.push_back(temp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply; However, I'd be particularly interested why my snippet produces a different result on linux  and mac...:o)

Comment: @Marco: My first guess would be that the library you're using on the Mac simply has a bug.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd be particularly interested why my snippet produces a different result on linux and mac...

I think this behavior is due to differences in how floating point inputs are handled in input streams in Libc++ vs. Libstdc++ (rather than Mac vs. Ubuntu)

You're most likely using Libc++ (LLVM/Clang's standard C++ library) on Mac since [Apple deprecated Libstdc++](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes) (the GNU standard C++ library that comes standard in Linux).

In this case, Libc++ will "eat" any characters that could potentially be converted into a double, while Libstdc++ will not (e.g. it "eats" the `pe` in `peter` because `p` and `e` could potentially be part of the representation of a double).

For example, if your `students.txt` looked like this:

```
0x1a 90.2 84.3
0x1a 1.5 56.4
```

When you compile your original program with Libstdc++ and run it, you get:

```
0x1a 90.2 84.3 0 
x1a 1.5 56.4
```

While compiling it with Libc++ and running gives:

```
0x1a 90.2 84.3 26 1.5 56.4
```

Libc++ recognizes `0x1a` as a hex number (26), while Libstdc++ only converts the `0` in `0x1a` and parses `x1a` into the string name.

For a much more detailed explanation including examples, see https://github.com/tardate/LittleCodingKata/blob/master/cpp/DoubleTrouble/README.md