# C++ - Reading a double, followed by a character, from cin

Tags: c++, cin

I'm trying to read a double, followed by a character, from cin using the snippet:

```
double d;
char c;
while(1) {
    cin >> d >> c;
    cout << d << c << endl;
}
```

The peculiar thing is that it works for some characters, but not for others. For example, it works for "2g", "2h", but fails for "2a", "2b", "2x" ...:

mwmbp:ppcpp mwisse$ ./a.out

2a
0
2b
0
2c
0
2g
2g
2h
2h
2i
0h
2x
0h
2z
2z

As pointed out by one of you, it does indeed work for integers. Do you know why it doesn't work for doubles? I have as yet been unable to find information on how cin interprets its input.

Comment: Did you happen to use `cin >> std::hex` earlier in the program

Comment: In stroustrup's example he is probably reading into `int`. The rules for reading a `double` are different and do admit various letters, e.g. `x`, `p`, `e`

Comment: I just tried this and it works for me for "2a" and "2b". Can you give your specific stdin input for which it fails?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. [Cannot reproduce](http://ideone.com/1ACqxU).

Comment: I [can't reproduce](http://ideone.com/bzamAb) with exactly those examples. There must be something more in your code that messes things up (or you didn't reproduce your code exactly).

Comment: Hi M.M, No I didn't use std::hex. Yes, you're right - it does work for integers. Could you tell me why it doesn't for doubles? Thanks!

Comment: @Marco I have spelled out *exactally* how the `istream` extraction operators work and provided sources on that. Your `double` extraction operator is not compliant, or there's something in your code that's causing the issue.

Comment: @M.M As it turns out `hex` is for integers and has no effect on a double: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37461993/2642059

Comment: @Marco You've accepted my answer, and I appreciate that, but it was just pointing out that the results that you were presenting weren't possible without 1) a non-conformant library 2) there was a state introduced outside the code in your question that caused this. Were you able to confirm what the issue was? Is `cin` already in a bad state when you try to extract the double perhaps?

Comment: @Jonathan: The problem does seem to lie with the compiler, because it works fine with g++ 4.8.2 on linux, but fails using Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72), which is what comes with the latest version of xcode. I've sent an email to the llvm mailing list to see if they can shed some more light on the matter.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Turns out Marco *did* provide an MCVE. This is a bug in LLVM: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37460824/2642059

Comment: @molbdnilo Turns out Marco *did* give us complete code. The failure is with LLVM: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37460824/2642059

Comment: @Marco Yeah I'v put a link to the bug against it in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37460824/2642059) If you happen to rustle up any proposed fix or work around on the mailing list you might consider posting it here as the correct answer.

Comment: @Jonathan Well what do you know :o)! Thanks very much for your help. If I find out any more I'll be sure to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently a bug on LLVM: https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17782
Way back in 2014 it was assigned from Howard Hinnant to Marshall Clow since then... Well don't hold you breath on this getting fixed any time soon.

**EDIT:**

The [`istream` extraction operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) internally uses [`num_get::do_get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get) Which sequentially performs these tasks for a `double`:

1. Selects a conversion specifier, for `double` that's `%lg`
2. Tests for an empty input stream
3. Checks if the next character in the string is contained in the [`ctype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype) or [`numpunct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/numpunct) `facet`s
4. If [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) would allow the character obtained from **3** to be appended to the input field given the conversion specifier obtained in **1**, if so **3** is repeated if not **5** is performed on the input field without this character
5. The `double` from the accepted input field is read in with

   - [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) prior to [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)
   - [`strtold`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof) in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) and [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14)
   - [`strtod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof) onward from [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)
6. If **5** fails [`failbit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) is assigned to the `istream`'s [`iostate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate), but if **5** succeeded, the result is assigned to the `double`
7. If any thousands separators were allowed into the input field by `facet numpunct` in **3** their position is evaluated, if any of them violate the `grouping` rules of the `facet`, `failbit` is assigned to the `istream`'s `iostate`
8. If the input field used in **5** was empty [`eofbit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) is assigned to the `istream`'s `iostate`

That's a lot to say that for a `double` you're really concerned with `scanf`'s `%lg` conversion specifier's rules for extraction of a `double` (which internally will depend upon [`strtof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof)'s constraints):

1. An optional plus or minus character
2. One of the following

   - "INF" or "INFINITY" (case insensitive)
   - "NAN" (case insensitive)
   - "0x" or "0X", an input field of hexadecimal digits and optionally a decimal point character, and optionally followed by a "p" or "P" a plus or minus sign and a *decimal* exponent
   - An input field of decimal digits and optionally a decimal point character and optionally an "e" or "E" a plus or minus sign and a non-empty exponent

Note that if your `locale` defines any other expression as an acceptable floating point input field this is also accepted. So if you've added some special sauce to the `istream` you're working with that may be where the problem lies. Outside of that, neither a trailing "a", "b", or "x" are an accepted suffix for the `%lg` conversion specifier, so your implementation is not compliant or there's something else you're not telling us.

Here is a live example of your inputs succeeding on gcc5.1 which is compliant: http://ideone.com/nGGW0L

Comment: Wow, thanks for your reply! It'll take me some time to digest, but it looks very helpful! I'll try a few different environments and see if there's any difference.

Comment: @Marco Ah, great. I don't know how simple your code is but perhaps you could paste it into http://ideone.com to let me have a look at the unedited version?

Comment: OK, I've now tried it on two linux machines, both with g++ 4.8.4, and it works fine. The machine where it fails is a Mac, using llvm 7.0.0. You'd hope that there wouldn't be any difference...(?). Do you use a general strategy for avoiding this sort of thing?

Comment: ah, hadn't seen your last comment yet - the 'edited' version is the actual one I ran :o).

Comment: @Marco Have a +1 you did find a non conformant point on LLVM. I have to say, work arounds are not pretty, they'd involve `sscanf`. Do you control the input? If so I'd say just make sure to space delineate your input.

Comment: OT, but this issue highlights a big problem area of iostreams. The rules for streaming in a `double` are complicated, change all the time, self-contradictory in places, and all implementations have bugs of some form.

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem is caused by a bug (or feature, depending on your point of view), in libc++, it seems that the easiest way to avoid it is to use libstdc++ instead, until a fix is in place. If you're running on a mac, add -stdlib=libstdc++ to your compile flags. g++ -stdlib=libstdc++ test.cpp will correctly compile the code given in this post.

Libc++ appears to have other, similar, bugs, one of which I posted here: [Trying to read lines from an ASCII file using C++ , Ubuntu vs Mac...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33478527/trying-to-read-lines-from-an-ascii-file-using-c-ubuntu-vs-mac), before learning about these different libraries.