# Reading a double from an istream in Hex

Tags: c++, hex, scanf, istringstream, iomanip

Given `double foo` I can assign it from a hex format string using `sscanf` like this:

```
sscanf("0XD", "%lg", &foo)
```

But I cannot seem to get an `istringstream` to behave the same way. All of these just write 0 to `foo`:

1. `istringstream("0XD") >> foo`
2. `istringstream("0XD") >> hex >> foo`
3. `istringstream("D") >> hex >> foo`

This is particularly concerning when I read [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get) that the `double` `istream` extraction operator should:

> The check is made whether the `char` obtained from the previous steps is allowed in the input field that would be parsed by `std::scanf` given the conversion specifier

Why can't I read hex from an `istream`? I've written some test code [here](http://ideone.com/Dkud7R) if it would be helpful in testing.

Comment: Apply a cast may be?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Can you help me understand what you're suggesting? I don't wand to read in an integer and cast to a `double`, if that's what you're saying, I'm just extracting something simple for the sake of clarity here.

Comment: It doesn't look like streams were made to do this.  I wonder if it comes from the fact that hex literals are treated as int's so the stream library treas hex input the same way.

Comment: @NathanOliver Not that I'd suggest it's authoritative but: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get says that I should be able to use hexadecimal characters in my input field.

Comment: It's not available, at least not yet. [The reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal) also says that in C++17 the exponent character for hex float will be `P`. But P is not in the list of `0123456789abcdefABCDEFxX+-` used by the streams. Might get fixed before next standard release, or not?

Comment: @molbdnilo You say: "the input is first filtered as if `scanf` would read it in decimal." Yet [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get) is saying that `"0123456789abcdefxABCDEFX+-"` are accepted which work fine, integer or decimal.

Comment: @BoPersson Good comment. I hadn't actually noticed that. Maybe that's why nothing conforms to this yet? Cause they couldn't get the exponent right?

Comment: @molbdnilo The point is that we're working with the `%lg` modifier from Stage 1, which would allow the hex characters. In any event, I think that the actual guard on the allowed characters is [`hexfloat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed), when that is specified everything is peachy.

Comment: @BoPersson It looks like when [`hexfloat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) is used "p" and "P" *are* accepted...

Comment: @JonathanMee Yeah, I was completely confused (I even managed to write a botched test program to "prove" my confusion was correct <blush/>). I'm removing my inane ramblings. Sorry for being a time-waster.

Comment: @molbdnilo Not a problem at all. I appreciate you taking the time to consider my issues!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [hexfloat](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) modifier. The `hex` modifier is for integers.

On compliant compilers this will solve your problem.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double foo;

    sscanf("0xd", "%lg", &foo);
    cout << foo << endl;

    istringstream("0xd") >> hexfloat >> foo;
    cout << foo << endl;

    istringstream("d") >> hexfloat >> foo;
   cout << foo << endl; 
}
```

Using [Visual Studio 2015](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) will produce:

> 13
>   13
>   13

Using [libc++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b383f5f18d83d18) will produce:

> 13
>   13
>   0

So I'm not sure of the legitimacy of `istringstream("d") >> hexfloat >> foo`

Comment: Nice.. but is there a difference between your second and third test cases 'istringstream("0xd") >> hexfloat >> foo;'?  If so my eyes are not seeing it.

Comment: @DaleWilson Well, said, I was so excited about finding `hexfloat` that I just straight edited the code from the question without thinking. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This, including loopback seems to work fine with two recent compilers and at least c++17, for example:

MSVC 16.7.0 Preview 2 C++ std /latest

Clang 10.0.0 -std=c++2a

but fails for GCC, for example:

GCC 10.0.1 -std=c++2a using libstd++

This bug is suspended awaiting a decision by the C++ standards WG21

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla//show_bug.cgi?id=81122

Bug 81122 - [DR 2381] parsing f stopped after '0' when reading std::hexfloat >> f;

https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2381 Last modified: 2018-08-24

and appears to have stalled for reasons unclear :-(