# Difference reading a double from stream between g++/stdlib++ and clang++/libc++

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, stringstream, libc++

minimal "failing" example:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
int main(int argv, char** argc) {
  std::string line = "1.1", line2 = "1.1X";
  std::istringstream iss(line), iss2(line2);
  double x;
  assert(iss >> x);
  std::cout << x << "\n" << std::flush;
  assert(iss2 >> x);
  std::cout << x << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Running with clang:

```
>clang++ -stdlib=libc++ reading_double.cc -o reading_double
>./reading_double 
1.1
reading_double: reading_double.cc:11: int main(int, char **): Assertion `iss2 >> x' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
>clang --version
Ubuntu clang version 18.0.0 (++20231004042239+548d67a0393c-1~exp1~20231004042400.1224)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

Running with gcc:

```
>g++ reading_double.cc -o reading_double
>./reading_double 
1.1
1.1
>g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Which is the correct behavior ? (the way I see it, libc++ is wrong)

Comment: It seems clang is wrong. It is possible to extract a `double` from `iss2` as well so I don't get why the assertion fails.

Comment: It seems related to [bug 17782](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17782). See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689378/characters-extracted-by-istream-double or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37459179/c-reading-a-double-followed-by-a-character-from-cin

Comment: @Bob__ So, should I mark this as duplicate ? or should you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it (the question you refer to is somewhat misleading IMO, but the bug report is spot on)

Comment: There probably are more dupe candidates, that bug report was issued almost ten years ago and [LWG 2381](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2381) submitted by Marshal Clow to fix the standard doesn't even resolve your specific case (the `'X'`). Feel free to post a self answer if you don't find a more suitable dupe target.

Answer (score 0):

Per the discussion with @Bob_ in the comments.
This is known bug in libc++
The most in depth discussion of this bug I found is at

https://github.com/tardate/LittleCodingKata/blob/main/cpp/DoubleTrouble/README.md